# How do I get the value of a field with generic typeof

Tags: c#, generics, typeof, setvalue, getvalue

Given that I have a parameter `TEntity` which will be an class, how do i get the value of one of its fields.

```
public class ProductStrategy<TContract> : IContractCreatorStrategy<TContract>
{
    public IContract<TContract> CreateContract<TEntity>(TEntity dbEntity)
    {
        var productEntity = Convert.ChangeType(dbEntity, typeof(TEntity));

        var contractType = typeof (TContract);
        var entityType = dbEntity.GetType();

        var contract = Activator.CreateInstance(contractType);

        var contractFields = contractType.GetProperties().ToList();
        var entityFields = entityType.GetProperties().ToList();

        foreach (var contractField in contractFields)
        {
            foreach (var entityField in entityFields)
            {
                if (entityField.Name.Contains(contractField.Name))
                {

//get the value of the entityfield and set the contract field value to the it.
                }
            }

        }

        return new ProductContract<TContract>();
        return productContract;
    }
}
```

Comment: _" i do not understand how to use the GetValue method"_ - try reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385(v=vs.110).aspx): you need to pass an object instance of which you want to get that particular property value

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you, this made me think of it and i was able to solve the issue. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fieldValue = entityField.GetValue(dbEntity, null);
contractField.SetValue(contract, fieldValue);
```